# Waht is the reason the electrons cannot occupy p-orbitals of the K shell?

Tags: orbitals

What is the ultimate reason, that the electrons cannot occupy the p-orbitals of the K shell?
Why for example, is there no element having electron configuration 1s<sup>2</sup> 1p<sup>3</sup>? And is it possible to excite the electron(s) of hydrogen or helium to the 1p-orbital(s)?

Comment: The reason is simple: **1p orbital is not a thing at all**. Why there are sport exercises where you use the strength of one of your hands (arm wrestling), or two of your hands (pull-ups), but never three? Why, really? Same thing here.

Answer (score 3):

Electrons with the energy quantum number $n$ can have orbital angular momentum quantum number $\ell = 0, \dots, n-1$ only.

Therefore, with $\ell = 0$, there is just the orbital 1s and no orbital 1p with $\ell = 1$.

For the same reason, there are no orbitals 2d nor 3f.